# Information asymmetry modeling

Tags: microeconomics, finance, bayesian-game, asymmetric-information

Is there any cook book, in finance, for models in information asymmetry, so as to make some practice?

Comment: there are a lot of such models in market microstructure research but I don't know if that's what you're after.  also, I don't know of a cookbook about it where you can practice ?

Comment: @mark leeds could ypu recommend me some model twith potential, in the sense that someone could make his/her own inovvations no matter how difficult is semms to be

Comment: can you get hands on marcos's book on PIN ? I think he made a book out of his thesis and I have it somewhere. It may be useful as far as exploring innovations ? I'm not upto speed on information asymmetry so I can't recommend a specific model. His thesis discusses atleast one and maybe multiple models.

Comment: @mark leeds tell me more details about the book or the author because i can not find something by searching ``marcos's book on PIN ". Thank you in advance!

Comment: I apologize for not being more specific. I forget that marcos is not known by everyone on the planet :). let me look for it and get back to you.

Comment: Hi: here's a summary of this thesis. I'm sure if you email marcos, he will tell you how to download the full thesis. Unfortunately, I have it in book form but i can't find it on net. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c38a/47245311ad0a816270a7bc174b4800186e4d.pdf

Comment: Well, this is not exaclty what I am looking for...but maybe it can help me in some way! Thank you again!

Comment: Not really a cookbook, but "Asset Pricing under Asymmetric Information" by Brunnermeier might be worth looking into.