# Economic predictions and the general intelligence systems research?

Tags: reference-request

So I have physics background. And I'm guessing a lot of economists have asked "what is the time evolution of society after general intelligence is discovered?" What is the state of the art research, etc on this?

Comment: I don't think this is a question a lot of economists have asked. In any case, your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "time evolution of society" and what do you mean by the discovery of "general intelligence"?

Comment: Would you recommend I migrate this question? (To some other SE)

Comment: Also why isn't this funded in economics? Like what would this do to economies?

Comment: There is theoretical research on how AI might affect jobs and so on. There might be a research also in other areas outside labor economics. However, this is too broad of question. Already providing (brief) answer for impact of AI on labor market would take about one page of text. You are literally asking for an impact on every market out there. SE format is not suitable for broad questions that require hundreds of pages of text to answer. I get that these big questions are interesting but unless you break them down they are too big for stack exchange format